# Every morning the lecturer chooses pairs of students

Tags: probability

> There are 10 students in a class 7 males and 3 female. Every morning the lecturer chooses pairs of students in a random.

X - numbets of teams, including a man and a woman (together)

**I thought about it this way:**
$$P(X) = P (x = 1) + P (x = 3)$$

$P(x = 2)$ can not be ,beacuse it requires 3 pairs.

So how to calculate $P(X)$?

Comment: This question is impossible to read.  Please take some time to edit it and be sure to fix the following problems: 1) there is no question!  2) what do you mean by $P(X)$?  As you've defined it $X$ is a number (random variable), not an event (something that may or may not occur with some probability).

Comment: If $X$ is the number of "mixed" pairs, then indeed the only possibilities are $X=1$ and $X=3$. Are you asked to find the distribution of the random variable $X$?

Comment: @André Nicolas I was asked to calculate $P (X)$

Comment: Can you post the exercise word for word ?

Comment: I think it is accessible. Just as a check on your calculations, $\Pr(X=3)=\frac{7}{12}$ (do this one first) and therefore $\Pr(X=1)=\frac{5}{12}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Not for me. But it doesn´t matter.

Answer (score 1):

The women are Alicia, Beti, and Cecile.

Let us suppose (it does not alter the probability) that they are assigned partners first, in that order. The probability Alicia is partnered with a man is $7/9$. *Given* this has happened, the probability Beti is partnered with a man is $6/8$. Thus $\Pr(X=3)=\frac{7}{9}\cdot \frac{6}{8}$. For the probability that $X=1$, subtract this from $1$.